# Rails call a class from a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, datatable

I have a rails 3.2 application where I use differents gem that I have created. I have a folder People and a folder Magazine, so in people I have a file

```
module Essa::Person
 class CarsDatatable < AjaxDatatablesRails::Base
```

I want to call CarsDatatable in a external module. How is the syntax to initialize CarsDatatable in a controller of the folder Magazione.

For example i try

```
CarsDatatable.new

or 

Essa::Person::CarsDatatable

but I have an error
```

Comment: What is the location of **People** folder? Also, did you try to include the module like `include Essa::Person`

Comment: What's the error you are getting? Update the question with that.

Comment: Is possibile to call the class and specific the path? The path of my folders are /home/essa/Modules/rails_3.2

Comment: Just define `include Essa::Person` at the top of your controller where you need to call `CarsDatatable`. Then in any method inside that controller initialise the class like `Essa::Person::CarsDatatable.new`. It's better practice to have your modules inside `lib` folder